# Retrieve parameter value from testNG.xml file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, testng

[image]

I want to print the value **"iPhone5"** from the key **parameter name ="webdriver.deviceName.iPhone"** .

Comment: Could you please share code as per the above xml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically two ways in which you do this from within a Test Class (A test class is essentially a class that houses one or more `@Test`/configuration methods)

1. Via the `ITestContext` object. You can get access to the current method's `ITestResult` object by calling `Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext()`
2. Using Native injection wherein you have TestNG inject a `ITestContext` object.  For more details on native injection please refer to the TestNG documentation [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection)

Here's a sample that shows both these in action.

```java
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTestClass {

  private static final String KEY = "webdriver.deviceName.iPhone";

  @BeforeClass
  public void beforeClass(ITestContext context) {
    String value = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter(KEY);
    System.err.println("webdriver.deviceName.iPhone = " + value);
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    String value = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter(KEY);
    System.err.println("webdriver.deviceName.iPhone = " + value);
  }
}
```